# Generate FastAPI docs from msgspec.Struct json schema

Tags: python, fastapi, jsonschema, pydantic

One can generate a json schema from a [`msgspec.Struct`](https://jcristharif.com/msgspec/structs.html) using [`msgspec.json.schema`](https://jcristharif.com/msgspec/jsonschema.html). Where does one put that schema so that FastAPI uses it as the schema for the endpoint's response body in the OpenAPI docs that it generates?

There doesn't seem to be a way to achive this in FastAPI despite some [schema customization options](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/#combine-predefined-responses-and-custom-ones). Nor is it possible to generate a pydantic model (so that it could be used for the docs) [from a json schema](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6598).

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but maybe look into [Litestar](https://litestar.dev/)? The interface is similar to FastAPI uses `msgspec` for models.

Comment: It's a big project in production, there should be an easier way than changing frameworks just to change the docs for one endpoint.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation on [extending the OpenAPI schema](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/extending-openapi/)?

Comment: You can add stuff to the schema but not provide one in full.

Comment: Not sure I understand, by overriding `app.openapi`, you can modify the OpenAPI schema as a dictionary in any way you want?